# error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'

Tags: java, android, decompiling, decompiler

hi i am a beginner for android i was decompile an app and i det the code source but when i import it on eclipse its give me this error:

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
```

i try some tips that i found it in stack-overflow but not working 
if you know the solution help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may caused you haven't installed API > 21 in your computer (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

Open SDK Manager and install it.

And another important thing i want to talk about is why you use Eclipse instead of Android Studio? eclipse is now no longer supported by Google

Comment: yes i know this android studio it's work without problems in 4G (ram ) for me i don't have 4 G that is the problem ... can u show me how i will install this API 21 step by step

Comment: You can open SDK manager from android SDK folder.(SDK Manager.exe). Then a new dialog opened with a list of components, You'll see what you need to install :)